# hide Programmatically apk in drawer-android 11

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I need help.
how to Programmatically hide android app in drawer for android 11 & 11+
I red all topic in internet but they were old.
thanks :)

I red all topic in internet but they were old.
or how to add botun in android apk for hidden app?